# The Path is Not Working ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, filepath, email-attachments

I've been trying to path the attachment so that I can upload/attach it in the email when I send it. I can receive the Name, Email, Subject, and Message. But somehow there's no attachment in the message I receive. I'm not sure what's the problem. I'm just new with this kind of stuffs. Someone please help me. Thank you. This the code in my controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(EmailFormModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads");
        List<string> paths = new List<string>();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            }
            paths.Add(path);
        }

        //Attach files
        foreach (var path in paths)
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = fileInfo.OpenRead())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            }
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            string fileName = fileInfo.Name;
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, fileName));
        }

        //Rest of business logic here
        string EncodedResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];
        bool IsCaptchaValid = (ReCaptcha.Validate(EncodedResponse) == "True" ? true : false);
        if (IsCaptchaValid)
        {

            var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Subject: {2} </p><p>Message:</p><p>{3}</p>";
            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("***@gmail.com"));  // replace with valid value 
            message.From = new MailAddress("***@ymailcom");  // replace with valid value
            message.Subject = "Your email subject";
            message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.FromSubject, model.Message);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = "***@gmail.com",  // replace with valid value
                    Password = "***"  // replace with valid value
                };
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                //return RedirectToAction("Sent");
                ViewBag.Message = "Your message has been sent!";

                //TempData["message"] = "Message sent";
                ModelState.Clear();
                return View("Index");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            TempData["recaptcha"] = "Please verify that you are not a robot!";
        }
    }
    return View(model);

}
```

And here's the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @*Send Message*@
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="contact_form block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div id="note"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="fields">

                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromName)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromEmail)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromEmail)
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromSubject)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromSubject, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromSubject)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <label for="file1">Attachments</label>
                        <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" multiple/>

                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-12">                 
                     <div>
                         @if ((TempData["recaptcha"]) != null)
                         {
                            <p>@TempData["recaptcha"]</p>   
                         }
                     </div>
                     <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfVHx8TAAAAAMTDxxQrHDCxO1SyXf1GgbgNBZ5a"></div>
                 </div>

                <div class="col-md-12"><input class="shortcode_button" type="submit" value="Send"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Your `message.Attachments.Add(..` line of code will throw an exception because you do not even declare `var message = new MailMessage();` until after that code (have you shown the correct code?)

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Thank you Sir! It's one error down. But there's still error in "local variable path". Yes the codes after that have no errors.

Comment: You need to move `var message = new MailMessage();` to before the `foreach (var path in paths)` line.

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's okay now Sir. I was just missing a curly bracket. Thank you so much for your help Sir!